# Linux and Dialog

Tags: linux, menu, dialog

I apologise for how simple this question is but I'm currently learning.

I'm using dialog in Linux and I would like an option to take me to another dialog menu with more options, basically another menu.

````
HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="this is a back title"
TITLE="title"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"
MENU2="This is another menu"

OPTIONS=(1 "Install this"
         2 "menu 2"
         3 "menu 3"
         4 "menu 4")

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                --title "$TITLE" \
                --menu "$MENU" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

                clear
case $CHOICE in
        1)
            mkdir -p /opt/test
            ;;
        2)
            Dialogue_menu_2
            ;;
        3)
            echo "test3"
            ;;
        4)
            echo "worked"            
            ;;    
esac ```

This is what I have so far I just can't see how I can get it working. Apologies again but I cannot find much online about this tool.
````

Answer (score 0):

I use function to do this

something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

function menu1(){
  local HEIGHT=15
  local WIDTH=40
  local CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
  local BACKTITLE="this is a back title"
  local TITLE="Menu 1"
  local MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

  local OPTIONS=(
    1 "Install this"
    2 "menu 2"
    3 "test 3"
    4 "test 4"
  )

  local CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
    --title "$TITLE" \
    --menu "$MENU" \
    $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
    "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
    2>&1 >/dev/tty
  )
  echo $CHOICE
}

function menu2(){
  local HEIGHT=15
  local WIDTH=40
  local CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
  local BACKTITLE="this is a back title"
  local TITLE="Menu 2"
  local MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

  local OPTIONS=(
    1 "Option 1"
    2 "Option 2"
    3 "Option 3"
    4 "Option 4"
  )

  local CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
    --title "$TITLE" \
    --menu "$MENU" \
    $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
    "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
    2>&1 >/dev/tty
  )
  echo $CHOICE
}

# Main
# Call menu1 and register in $RET1
RET1=$(menu1)
case $RET1 in
        1)
            mkdir -p /opt/test
            ;;
        2)
            #Call menu2 and register in $RET2
            RET2=$(menu2)
            echo "You choose for menu 1: $RET1"
            echo "You choose for menu 2: $RET2"
            ;;
        3)
            echo "test3"
            ;;
        4)
            echo "worked"
            ;;    
esac
```

Function menu1 is called and the selected option is stored in $RET1 and use by the case

```
menu1
 └─> echo "Install this"
 └─> Call function menu2
        └─> echo "choose menu1: "
        └─> echo "choose menu2: "
 └─> echo "test3"
 └─> echo "test4"
```

I hope this is clearest :-)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.